# C# SpeechRecognitionEngine CultureInfo Language

Tags: c#

I tried the SpeechRecognitionEngine from Microsoft. I used the basic example code from [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.speech.recognition.speechrecognitionengine(v=vs.110).aspx).

But my problem is that the CultureInfo throws an exception caused by the language "en-US" since Im from germany.

Is there any way I can solve that?

Comment: The only voice that is for free is the one that is included with your language-specific version of Windows.  Other languages require shopping.

Comment: Ok, so where can I buy these?